# Show dock only in activities

Tags: gnome, panel, dock, activities-overview, autohide

On my PC, I had a Hot-Corner with the action to open activities menu. The dock showed up only when I open the activities, and I liked that. Recently, I had problem with my display manager (which I will not relate here) and it needed me to reinstall GNOME. After this, the display-manager issue is resolved but now the dock shows up on my desktop. Is there a way to hide it on the desktop and show it only in the activities menu? Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**

How it is now:

[image]

Here is where I want it to be:

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Hi John, can you post the output of `echo $DESKTOP_SESSION`

Comment: Here it is: `ubuntu`

Comment: Hi @JohnCarter I am very sorry for late reply. You could simply disable the system-wide extension dash-to-dock

Comment: Thank you very much, @PRATAP!

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt remove ubuntu-desktop
```

```
sudo apt install vanilla-gnome-desktop
```

to use plain gnome (not ubuntu version)

Comment: Hey @petep, won't the command `sudo apt remove ubuntu-desktop` mess up Ubuntu Bugdie? I have it installed. Thank you!

Comment: ive done the same on 18.04 and had no problems

Comment: i dont know. be careful & backup first

Answer (score -1):

You probably installed the GNOME desktop. To restore the previous experience, you will have to reinstall the Ubuntu Desktop package. Open a terminal and enter the command

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

Then, choose Ubuntu (not GNOME) session in the login screen.

[image]

[Image source](https://www.linuxcapable.com/how-to-install-xfce-on-ubuntu-linux/)

Comment: No, I have ubuntu desktop installed (And I am sure that I didn't install gnome desktop). Thank you, though.